# Htaccess add trailing slash to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to add trailing slash to root URL?
For example, I need `https://domain.example` -> `https://domain.example/`

Comment: Please do add your tried .htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: `https://domain.example` and `https://domain.example/` are the same URL - there is _always_ a slash immediately after the hostname (at the start of the URL-path), even if you do not see it in the browser's address bar (it is present in the HTTP request). See the following question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

`https://domain.example` and `https://domain.example/` are the same URL - there is always a slash immediately after the hostname (at the start of the URL-path), even if you do not see it in the browser's address bar (it is present in the HTTP request).

The browser "prettifies" the URL you see in the address bar - this is not necessarily the exact URL that the browser uses in the request.

See the following question on the Webmasters stack:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser